# How to only get some of the *attributes/parameters* of a parent class in java

Tags: java, parent-child, parent, extends

i am having some trouble with my code, the main class has String n, int s, int d, int i

```
public class Maincharacter {
static Dice dice = new Dice();
private final String name;
private final int strength;
private final int dexterity;
public int intelligence;

public Maincharacter(String n, int s, int d, int i){
    this.name = n;
    this.strength = s;
    this.dexterity = d;
    this.intelligence = i;
}
```

and i need to make 3 extended classes getting the same attributes but has differences in them which is

```
 public class Mage extends Maincharacter {
static Dice dice = new Dice();
private int maxMagic;
public int currentMagic;
private int heal;


public Mage(String n, int s, int d){
   super (n,s,d);
   this.maxMagic = 100;
   this.currentMagic = maxMagic;
}
```

I only want to get String n, int s, and int d, but the error says that it differs in length, that i also need to add int i to it.

Sorry if there is some confusion or it may be vague but i dont know how to code that much.

Comment: you have passed only 3 parameters to super class by super key word from Mage class, but supper class constructor require 4 parameters.

Answer (score 1):

you have passed

> super (n,s,d);

but super class constructor asking 4 parameters, so you should pass 4 parameters into Mage class constructor

> super (n,s,d,/* another parameter should pass*/);

Comment: Agreed. You need to pass the mage's intelligence to the super class. If that's not meaningful, you could supply a value of 0.

Comment: if you think intelligence is 0 for instantiation then you can can do it simply like : super (n,s,d,0);